# Writing to the Manifest.xml during runtime

Tags: android

I have created a project as a Library, the library is setting up an `ActionBarSherlock` with a `SlideMenu`. Inside this `Slidemenu` i have a `ListView`. When the user presses one of this items inside this `ListView` a new `Activity` is supposed to start. My ListView has an adapter like this one:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    Activity act;
    ArrayList<SlideMenuItem> menuItemList;

    public MenuAdapter(Activity act, int workflowMenu) {
        this.act = act;
        this.context = act.getApplicationContext();
        parseXml(workflowMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return menuItemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidemenu_listitem, null);
            MenuItemHolder viewHolder = new MenuItemHolder();
            viewHolder.label = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menuLabel);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        MenuItemHolder holder = (MenuItemHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = menuItemList.get(position).label;
        holder.label.setText(s);
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(menuItemList.get(position).icon);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SlideMenuItem item = (SlideMenuItem) getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Id: " + Integer.toString(item.id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

    public class SlideMenuItem {
        public int id;
        public Drawable icon;
        public String label;
    }

    class MenuItemHolder {
        public TextView label;
        public ImageView icon;
    }

    private void parseXml(int menu) {

        menuItemList = new ArrayList<SlideMenuItem>();

        try {
            XmlResourceParser xpp = context.getResources().getXml(menu);

            xpp.next();
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                    String elemName = xpp.getName();

                    if (elemName.equals("item")) {

                        String textId = xpp.getAttributeValue(
                                "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
                                "title");
                        String iconId = xpp.getAttributeValue(
                                "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
                                "icon");
                        String resId = xpp.getAttributeValue(
                                "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
                                "id");

                        SlideMenuItem item = new SlideMenuItem();
                        item.id = Integer.valueOf(resId.replace("@", ""));
                        item.icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                                Integer.valueOf(iconId.replace("@", "")));
                        item.label = resourceIdToString(textId);

                        menuItemList.add(item);

                        Log.v("ADDED ITEM LABEL: ", item.label); //This triggers with the right labels, so the listview does exist!
                    }

                }

                eventType = xpp.next();

            }
            Log.v("MenuList: ", "Size: " + Integer.toString(menuItemList.size()));
            for(SlideMenuItem item : menuItemList) {
                Log.v("MenuList: ", Integer.toString(item.id) + ": " + item.label);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String resourceIdToString(String text) {
        if (!text.contains("@")) {
            return text;
        } else {
            String id = text.replace("@", "");
            return context.getResources().getString(Integer.valueOf(id));

        }
    }
}
```

The workflowMenu parameter is a xml file holding the menu items, so the listview can be populated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Item 1">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Item 2">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_three"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Item 3">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_four"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Item 4">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_five"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Item 5">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_seven"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Item 6">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_six"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Item 7">
    </item>
</menu>
```

From my MainProject, the library is called like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseWindow {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.InitializeWindow(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, R.menu.slide_menu, "Home"); 


    }
```

Where `BaseWindow` will setup all the neccessary GUI. The problem occurs when I want to start a new Activity, when the user presses one item in the listView in my library.

if the `listview` was constructed in the same project as the I could just specify the Activities in one `Manifest` file and start the activity inside the adapter like this:

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchActivity(position);
            }

        });

public void launchActivity(int position) {

    Class<?> cls = null;
    switch (menuItemList.get(position).id) {
        case R.id.item_one:
            cls = FirstClass.class;
            act.finish();
            break;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

But since the adapter is in another project(the library) I also have to declare the activities in the library manifest. I cant see how I should do so, if I dont know the name of this activity. And I guess there is no way to write to the manifest or create activity declaration during runtime due to security reasons.

Does anybody know what am trying to achieve here? Please give me some suggestions on how I can solve this.

Please just ask if something is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

hehehe)

you can just declare the activity from the library project inside the App project. But think closely on it: how will the Activity form the library know which activity to call on the app?

Most likely you'll want to extend the LibraryActivity in the your App project and include some portion of the code that only relates to that app.